# Errors in ascx control when getting ModuleID()

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

In Visual Studio I've been always getting the following errors when getting ModuleID in ascx, but the module compiles successfully. Any ideas how to fix these issues?

This is how I register the ascx:

```
 <%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="View.ascx.vb" Inherits="Christoc.Modules.babyList.View" %>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to access your Moduleid in ascx file

```
<%= ModuleId %>
```